# Column in Mantis BT database for 'assigned-to'?

Tags: mantis

I am trying to do some analysis using the data in Mantis BT database. Which column stores the person to whom an issue is assigned ? In the table called `'mantis_bug_table'` there is a column called `'handler_id'`. But i don't think that is the column we want.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. **handler_id** field in **mantis_bug_table** is used to store the user_id of the assigned user.

Here is a detailed schema with relationship. It's created for an old version (1.2), but I don't think there are many changes.

https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/developers/images/erd.png

Comment: I had seen this schema. However there is no mapping of these columns to the Mantis UI.